# Kafka exclude topics to subscribe to

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Currenly I am consuming multiple topcis by using this 'regex': `^device-*`

This regex lets me subscribe to

```
device-gnt-q100-a
device-gnt-q100-a-commands
device-ant-q100-b
device-ant-q100-b-commands
device-ant-q535-a
device-dnq-qpo-def
device-dnq-qpo-def-commands
device-gda-qpp001-xyz
device-gda-qpp001-xyz-commands
```

Is it possible to somehow exclude all topics that end with -commands?

Tried without success:

```
^(?!device-\w*-commands)device-*
^(?!.*[-]commands$)device-.*$
```

Comment: Regexes are inclusive, so if you want to ignore anything ending with `-commands`, using anything with `.*$` isn't correct as that'll capture it. Also, none of those names end in `device-`, so you shouldn't have that after the `(?!) ` group. Other than that, `device-*` doesn't match those names either, but `device-.*` does... Based on what you posted, `device-[ga]nt-q100-[ab]` will work, but maybe you have more examples?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added more examples. I do get all topics by using "^device-*" but maybe that's something special within kafka and does not apply to regexes in general?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Regexes do work. Negative lookaheads are difficult to work with, in my opinion, and should be avoided if possible

Comment: Still, if you want to exclude the `-commands`, all your examples would match "`device` followed by three hyphenated sections, of at least one character", so `^device(-[0-9a-z]{1,6}){3}$`

Answer (score 1):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2769) in the regex library used by librdkafka which fails on negative lookaheads.
I found a solution that works in my case altough it is on the uggly side:

```
^device-.*([^s]|[^d]s|[^n]ds|[^a]nds|[^m]ands|[^m]mands|[^o]mmands|[^c]ommands)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `^(?!device-\w*-commands)device-*`

Comment: This seems to subscribe to nothing at all.
Maybe i should have been more clear.

example topics are:
device-q100-a
device-q100-a-commands
device-q100-b
device-q100-b-commands

Comment: ^(?!.*[-]commands$)device-.*$ is a valid regex and works with the online regex testers but doesn't seem to work either.